# Installing Pip-3.2 on Cygwin

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin, pip

I have Python 3 installed on Cygwin. However, I am unable to install Python 3 packages via `pip`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: why not? have you installed pip for this python installation? what error do you get?

Comment: Pip is installed, but it installs the python 2 version of the package. For example, my script that requires pyyaml returns `ImportError: No module named yaml`, even after successfully running `pip install pyyaml`.

Comment: Then the `pip` script doesn't run with the correct python version. Try `/path/to/python3 -m pip install ...` instead. Also, check the shebang of the pip script.

Comment: @mata FYI, Python 2 is also installed. `usr/bin/python3 -m pip install pyyaml` returns `/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip`. Thus my original question; how does one install pip-3 on cygwin?

Comment: `python3 -m ensurepip` and `python2 -m ensurepip`. Look to https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0453/

Answer (score 130, accepted):

1)While installing cygwin, make sure you install the 
python/python-setuptools from the list. This will install "easy_install" package.

2) Type the following command:

```
easy_install-a.b pip
```

You must replace `a.b` with your python version which can be 2.7 or 3.4 or whatever else.

Comment: This answer worked great for me.  I had to take a couple extra steps because I work at a university:  First, I navigated to my install path (c:/cygwin64/bin/). Then had auto complete help me find the easy install file named slightly differnt: easy_install 2.7.9

Comment: I did this to end up in a state without eggs: `easy_install-2.7 pip && pip install 'pip<8' && pip install pip --upgrade`

Comment: for python3, use python3 & **python3-setuptools** packages. It's obvious, but one can forget about python**3**-setuptools

Comment: And don't forget the version (ie -2.7). I had another python distribution on my computer, and 'easy_install' invoked that one rather than cygwin's.

Answer (score 45):

If you have more than one python installation, then you need to install pip (and probably also setuptools) for each installation separately.
To do so, you can first download [`ez_setup.py`](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py) and run it with python3:

```
/usr/bin/python3 ez_setup.py
```

That should install setuptools, and also create an `easy_install` script for your python version, e.g. `/usr/bin/easy_install-3.2`, which you can use to install pip:

```
/usr/bin/easy_install-3.2 pip
```

This will install pip into your python3 site packages directory, and again create a script `/usr/bin/pip-3.2`, which you can use to install packages for this python version.

Alternatively you can follow the install instructions from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#installation-instructions) and [here](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html).

Comment: Excellent! I was able to solve my cygwin issue following this answer.

Comment: I am getting "OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied" this error while installing in cygwin. I have admin rights in that machine.

Comment: Link to ez_setup.py is dead

Answer (score 29):

I think [the alternative install instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html) linked by mata are simplest:

> To install pip, securely download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).
>
> Then run the following (which may require administrator access):
>
> ```
> python get-pip.py
> ```

Comment: fwiw, this seems to silently do nothing under cygwin -- not sure why :(

Comment: Works under Babun, on Windows 10 x64

Answer (score 15):

Since OP specifically talks about Python3, I think we need to specify that just in case the user already have Python2 installed, which is very likely.

```
# If you don't have Python3 already, use apt-cyg:
apt-cyg install python3

# First update pip, pip2 
pip2 install --upgrade pip 

# Install pip3:
python3 -m ensurepip

# Finally update pip3:
pip3 install --upgrade pip

$ pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
```

BTW. There are several forks of [apt-cyg](https://github.com/ilatypov/apt-cyg), but the best maintained is that of [kou1okada](https://github.com/kou1okada/apt-cyg), you'll love it.

---

**EDIT: 2018-11-15**

Because I started out not using *[virtualenv](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv)*, I recently had to refresh my Cygwin Python3 installation, and realized a few things in the process that should have been obvious, but can easily be forgotten.

- When installing and using Python3 on Cygwin (and probably on most other *nix distros), **only** install the basic Python3 interpreter as a Cygwin package. From then on, only use the **pip** installer.
- After you have installed or updated any python3 packages using *pip*, your  Cygwin package manager will complain that your package is `"Incomplete"`. That is because *pip* has replaced/updated the files in that package. Check with: `cygcheck.exe -c |grep Incomplete`.
  **Do not re-install those packages with Cygwin.**

```sh
# cygcheck.exe -c |grep Incomplete
python3-setuptools      34.3.2-1         Incomplete
```

So what I did, was clear out *all* python3 related Cygwin packages, **except** the Python3 itself. Then I re-installed the only one needed: `python3-setuptools`.

```sh
# apt-cyg remove python3-setuptools
apt-cyg install python3-setuptools

# Fix pip3 symlink (or just pip if you don't have python2)
ln -s /usr/bin/pip3.6 /usr/bin/pip3

# That also installs the Cygwin packages:  
# python3-appdirs, python3-packaging, python3-pyparsing, python3-six

# Now, update setuptools with pip:
pip3 install -U --force-reinstall --only-binary=:all: --no-clean --no-cache-dir setuptools

# pip list |grep setuptools
setuptools          40.5.0
```

That should have also have re-installed all the *setuptools* dependencies with the latest updates.

From now on, do yourself a favor and start using a virtual environment.

Comment: is `ensurepip` necessary because of cygwin? Usually, `pip` is on board, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html)

Comment: @Timo, for me it was, for whatever reason I was missing pip3 for python3

Comment: As long as you have `pip` installed, you can always symlink in `/usr/bin/`, but perhaps its more elegant to use the native *ensurepip* fix. IDK if I already had an old version or if it was installed along with `setuptools`, but I don't have the `ensurepip` package installed.

Comment: +1 for recommending kou1okada's fork of apt-cyg, it's the most fully-featured and best-maintained by far, been using it for years.

Answer (score 2):

On windows, you can use pip to install packages. If you have multiple python installations under cygwin, give the full python path e.g. 
Python 2

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 -m pip install pyyaml
```

Python 3

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 -m pip install pyyaml
```

In case you dont have pip installed install it using below command

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 -m ensurepip
```

or

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 -m ensurepip
```

Answer (score 0):

I just learned, inspired from https://www.scivision.co/install-pip-in-cygwin/ and the answer before, that instead of using pip, you just have to use pip2 for python2 or pip3 for python 3 in cygwin on windows. Wondered about this the whole day...