# Install python modules in cygwin

Tags: python, module, cygwin, installation

What is a way to instaill python modules within cygwin? I'm new to cygwin and couldn't find pip or anything like that in the setup.exe package. I've looked around and I can't find a definitive way to do it. Does anyone have advice?

Answer (score 6):

On windows, under cygwin follow the below steps.

1.Ensure python is installed in cygwin. Type python on the terminal of cygwin and it should launch the python shell. If it doesn't launch the setup file for cygwin and select python from the package list and install.
2. Now, install pip if it's not already installed. Provide full path if you have multiple python installations e.g.

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 -m ensurepip
/usr/bin/python3.6 -m ensurepip
```

3. Now, you can use pip to install the python package. Depending upon the installation in which you want the package to be installed, run below command(s)

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 -m pip install pyyaml
/usr/bin/python3.6 -m pip install pyyaml
```

Answer (score 2):

In standard python installation, pip like scripts goes under "*your_python_directory*\Scripts". (in my system C:\Python34\Scripts) Make sure you have added this path to system directories (Environment Variables). Then

```
pip.exe install my_package_name
```

will work fine.

Also for configuring within cygwin [this](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-env.html) will help.

PS: sorry for confusion though I thought you meant you have installed python separately from cygwin. I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641438/installing-pip-3-2-on-cygwin) thread answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing the python in windows.

Suppose you install the python in D drive, then just call the installed python from cygwin like

```
/cygdrive/d/Python37/python.exe
```

In this case, you would not get two versions of python (one in cygwin, one in windows). And you can call the python from other terminals as well.