# Cannot install Python Packages

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, package, portaudio

I'm trying to install some packages on python But i'm not able to do so and despite trying multiple ways to solve the issue, I've got nothing.

**1:** While trying to install os in python packages using pip. But I get the error: [*Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1*] everytime I run pip install os command. I have upgraded the setuptools. And I have installed ez_setup too, but nothing changes.

**2:** While installing LibportAudio-dev, I get this error ["*Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libportaduio (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for libportaduio*"]. 
Same problem is with python-dev an libportaudio-dev

I would really be thankful if anyone could help me solving these issues. I'm using python 2.7

Comment: What OS are you using? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641438/installing-pip-3-2-on-cygwin) might be helpful for 1:.

Comment: `libportaduio` makes me think that maybe the packager has made a typo in the `install_requires` list...

Comment: I'm using microsoft windows 10.