# "no support for this platform" running a pip command on cygwin

Tags: python, pip

I have pip and virtualenv installed through cygwin and I'm running a virtualenv on my project. All that is working fine. I have installed a few packages. But trying to run the project I'm getting:

```
NotImplementedError: no support for this platform
```

When I look into the Python packages in the virtualenv that are throwing the error, I find this line in a bunch of the init files:

```
if sys.platform == 'darwin':
```

I'm on a pc running cygwin and if I go into python interactive from the command line and print out 'sys.platform' I get 'Cygwin'

Is there some pip configuration that I need to set manually? Can I do that and reload the packages somehow?

Here's the full error (edited to exclude some client info)

```
 File "release_process/main.py", line 1, in <module>  
from core import orchestrator  
File "/[PROJECT PATH]/core/orchestrator.py", line 6, in <module>  
from services import BuildConfigService, SigningService, SCFSService, GitHubService, CDNService  
File "/[PROJECT PATH]/core/services/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>  
from buildconfig import BuildConfigService  
File "/[ENVIRONMENT PATH]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/buildconfig/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>  
from . import runpersistent  
File "/[ENVIRONMENT PATH]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/buildconfig/runpersistent/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>  
raise NotImplementedError('no support for this platform')
```

NotImplementedError: no support for this platform

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Pip-3.2 on Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641438/installing-pip-3-2-on-cygwin)

Comment: No, this is a different error, and not one addressed by that question as far as I can tell.

Comment: What package are you installing? Please include the full error message from pip in the question.

Comment: So, this isn't during package install, the packages are all installed. Like I said, I'm trying to run the project. I'll edit the question to include the full error.

Comment: The package says that it doesn't support your platform. Even if it installed correctly, it won't run correctly. You can try see if it runs properly under the `linux` configuration.

Comment: ...I really don't understand why there's a pip tag on this question at all. Is it some pip subcommand you're running that's pulling in the `buildconfig` library? If so, you'll want to look at who owns/wrote the `release_process` code, `orchestrator` code, etc. that's actually invoking that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a problem with pip, but with [the `buildconfig` library](https://github.com/mo22/buildconfig/blob/master/buildconfig/runpersistent/__init__.py), which is **not** part of `pip` but rather is pulled in by the application you're trying to install.

That library explicitly supports no platforms other than `darwin` or `linux`.

Comment: Argh. That makes sense. Thank you.